# Access Class methods without prefixing with class

Tags: java, class, methods

In a program like:

```
package testing;

import MarcoLib.Mouse;
import MarcoLib.Timings;

public class Testing {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Mouse.pressMouse(1);
}

}
```

Is there a way to call `Mouse.pressMouse()` without prefixing using Mouse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the method `pressMouse` is static, then you could [**Static Import**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html)  your method(s),

```
import MarcoLib.Mouse;
import MarcoLib.Timings;
import static MarcoLib.Mouse.pressMouse;

public class Testing {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    pressMouse(1);
  }
}
```

and per the link,

> So when should you use static import? **Very sparingly!**

If the method `pressMouse` isn't static, then you could extend `Mouse`,

```
import MarcoLib.Mouse;
import MarcoLib.Timings;

public class Testing extends Mouse {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Testing().pressMouse(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Gonna have to give you best answer for more/better info, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can import static methods:

```
import static com.company.Mouse.pressMouse;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    pressMouse(1); // No need to prefix with "Mouse."
}
```